# Add one element in the begin and one at end of an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to add two elements into an array. One in the beginning and one at end. I know I can do it in two statements. Using Array.unshift and then using Array.push

Is there any better way of doing this? In one statement.any help..

Comment: Why? Why is there a need for only one statement?

Comment: Make a function that takes two values and does both with the respective variable.

Comment: just wondering..if there is any better way of doing this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve when you say `better`?

Comment: In ES6 there is the new [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). `[1, ...[2, 3], 4]` Better? Not if you want to mutate the original array.

Comment: I believe that this is also counted as a single statement `(a.unshift(1), a.push(4), a)`, and mutates the original.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: @Xotic750 I liked the idea of comma operator.. it's new for me.. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

With `Array.concat`:

```
[1].concat([2,3,4], 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[first].concat(middle, [last]);
```

Comment: Why do you consider this better than an `Array#unshift` and an `Array#push`?

Comment: I don't. But it answers the question. It is single statement.

Comment: Other than being 1 statement, does it have any advantages or disadvantages compared to using the 2 statements? It's a single statement, but is it better?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.